# My flags have been waiting for review for 10+ days?

Tags: support, flagging, review, flags

I have several flags that I raised on the 5th... and they are still waiting for review.

What gives?

Comment: Busy mods? Crowded queues?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - But then how come flags that I've raised recently have gotten approved in less than an hour?

Comment: That I don't know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the flags you have currently pending are close flags (flags for the closure of questions). These aren't shown to moderators directly, but are placed [in a queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/stats) for users with 3,000, or more, reputation to review. It's a pretty big queue and each post requires an average of ~3 or so reviews to be considered "handled", it can take a wile.

All other flags are shown to moderators directly. We usually keep handling to a day or two, as best we can.